# Backup compression space allocation

Tags: backup, sql-server-2016

The backup size is big while taking backup and shrinks after the backup is completed. How I can make the backup compression effective during the backup processes, instead of the compression being effective at the completion of the backup.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server, etc.?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise

Comment: Define "big" and "smaller". I've seen backups initially show, say, 80 GB and wind up being 77 GB (presumably because it's estimating the amount of compression, and it's better to fail due to insufficient space right away than after running for hours); I assume the difference you're seeing is much more significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the documentation for [Backup Compression (SQL Server)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719(v=sql.110).aspx) (highlighting mine)

> **Allocation of Space for the Backup File**
>
> For compressed backups, the size of the final backup file depends on
>   how compressible the data is, and this is unknown before the backup
>   operation finishes. Therefore, by default, when backing up a database
>   using compression, the Database Engine uses a pre-allocation algorithm
>   for the backup file. This algorithm pre-allocates a predefined
>   percentage of the size of the database for the backup file. If more
>   space is needed during the backup operation, the Database Engine grows
>   the file. If the final size is less than the allocated space, at the
>   end of the backup operation, the Database Engine shrinks the file to
>   the actual final size of the backup.
>
> **To allow the backup file to grow only as needed to reach its final**
>   **size, use trace flag 3042. Trace flag 3042 causes the backup operation**
>   **to bypass the default backup compression pre-allocation algorithm.**
>   **This trace flag is useful if you need to save on space by allocating**
>   **only the actual size required for the compressed backup. However,**
>   **using this trace flag might cause a slight performance penalty (a**
>   **possible increase in the duration of the backup operation).**